# ExtJS model associations with jsonapi specification

Tags: json, extjs, model, associations, extjs4.2

We are creating a new version our API (v2) adopting the JSON:API specification (https://jsonapi.org/). I'm not being able to port the ExtJS model associations (belongs_to) to the new pattern.

The ExtJS documentation only shows how to use a nested relation in the same root node (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.association.Association).

v1 data (sample):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "description": "Software Development",
      "area_id": 1,
      "area": {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "01",
        "description": "Headquarters"
      }
    },
  ],
  "meta": {
    "success": true,
    "count": 1
  }
}
```

v2 data (sample):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "maint_service_nature",
      "attributes": {
        "id": 1,
        "description": "Software Development",
        "area_id": 1
      },
      "relationships": {
        "area": {
          "data": {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "area"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "included": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "area",
      "attributes": {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "01",
        "description": "Headquarters"
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "success": true,
    "count": 1
  }
}
```

My model:

```js
    Ext.define('Suite.model.MaintServiceNature', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    
        fields: [
            { desc: "Id", name: 'id', type: 'int', useNull: true },
            { desc: "Area", name: 'area_id', type: 'int', useNull: true },
            { desc: "Description", name: 'description', type: 'string', useNull: true, tableIdentification: true }
        ],
    
        associations: [
            {
                type: 'belongsTo',
                model: 'Suite.model.Area',
                foreignKey: 'area_id',
                associationKey: 'area',
                instanceName: 'Area',
                getterName: 'getArea',
                setterName: 'setArea',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: false
                }
            }
        ],
    
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url: App.getConf('restBaseUrlV2') + '/maint_service_natures',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data',
                record: 'attributes',
                totalProperty: 'meta.count',
                successProperty: 'meta.success',
                messageProperty: 'meta.errors'
            }
        }
    });
```

Any ideias on how to setup the association to work with the v2 data?

Comment: I think you're going to have to roll your own reader class... the framework isn't set up to deal with these kinds of structures.

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly taking a stab at this one... I haven't used Ext JS 4 in years, and I wouldn't structure my JSON like JSON:API does, but I think the only way you can accomplish this is by rolling your own `reader` class.  Given that you have generic properties for your data structure, this reader should work for all scenarios... although, I'm not too familiar with JSON:API, so I could be totally wrong.  Either way, [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3crk) is what I've come up with.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('MyReader', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.reader.Json',
            alias: 'reader.myReader',

            root: 'data',
            totalProperty: 'meta.count',
            successProperty: 'meta.success',
            messageProperty: 'meta.errors',

            /**
             * @override
             */
            extractData: function (root) {
                var me = this,
                    ModelClass = me.model,
                    length = root.length,
                    records = new Array(length),
                    dataConverter,
                    convertedValues, node, record, i;

                for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    node = root[i];
                    var attrs = node.attributes;
                    if (node.isModel) {
                        // If we're given a model instance in the data, just push it on
                        // without doing any conversion
                        records[i] = node;
                    } else {

                        // Create a record with an empty data object.
                        // Populate that data object by extracting and converting field values from raw data.
                        // Must pass the ID to use because we pass no data for the constructor to pluck an ID from
                        records[i] = record = new ModelClass(undefined, me.getId(attrs), attrs, convertedValues = {});

                        // If the server did not include an id in the response data, the Model constructor will mark the record as phantom.
                        // We  need to set phantom to false here because records created from a server response using a reader by definition are not phantom records.
                        record.phantom = false;

                        // Use generated function to extract all fields at once
                        me.convertRecordData(convertedValues, attrs, record, me.applyDefaults);

                        if (me.implicitIncludes && record.associations.length) {
                            me.readAssociated(record, node);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return records;
            }
        });

        Ext.define('Suite.model.Area', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

            fields: [{
                name: 'type',
                type: 'string'
            }]
        });

        Ext.define('Suite.model.MaintServiceNature', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

            fields: [{
                desc: "Id",
                name: 'id',
                type: 'int',
                useNull: true
            }, {
                desc: "Area",
                name: 'area_id',
                type: 'int',
                useNull: true
            }, {
                desc: "Description",
                name: 'description',
                type: 'string',
                useNull: true,
                tableIdentification: true
            }],

            associations: [{
                type: 'belongsTo',
                model: 'Suite.model.Area',
                associatedName: 'Area',
                foreignKey: 'area_id',
                associationKey: 'relationships.area.data',
                instanceName: 'Area',
                getterName: 'getArea',
                setterName: 'setArea'
            }],

            proxy: {
                type: 'rest',
                url: 'data1.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'myReader'
                }
            }
        });

        Suite.model.MaintServiceNature.load(null, {
            callback: function (record) {
                console.log(record.getData(true));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. With your solution I have the data from data.relationships.area on my record within the Area. But how can I get the data from included.attributes with area type within the Area on my record? This is needed to show the relation data on a grid for instance.

Comment: Oh, sorry... That structure is so confusing that I didn't understand what you needed.  I think you'd have to take off the root property and set up logic on where to look within your data.